# There is an error in XML document (27, 4) when deserializing XML from MemoryStream class

Tags: c#, xml, memorystream

When receiving XML data from an API I get this exception thrown.

{"The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value."}

There is an error in XML document (27, 4)

The XML data looks OK and I have used this code before for parsing similar XML. So I'm not sure what causing the exception.

The returned XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<agentInventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:N1="demo.org.uk/demo/CustomsStatus" xmlns:N2="demo.org.uk/demo/UnLocation" xmlns:N3="demo.org.uk/demo/AirCarrier" xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventory">
  <shed>TAX</shed>
  <arrivalPort>
    <N2:iataPortCode>LHR</N2:iataPortCode>
  </arrivalPort>
  <masterAirwayBillPrefix>125</masterAirwayBillPrefix>
  <masterAirwayBillNumber>25051155</masterAirwayBillNumber>
  <nominatedAgent>DRB</nominatedAgent>
  <originPort>
    <N2:iataPortCode>BOS</N2:iataPortCode>
  </originPort>
  <destinationPort>
    <N2:iataPortCode>LHR</N2:iataPortCode>
  </destinationPort>
  <airCarrier>
    <N3:carrierCode>BA</N3:carrierCode>
   </airCarrier>
  <flightNumber>123</flightNumber>
  <flightDate>2011-05-25T00:00:00Z</flightDate>
  <npx>10</npx>
  <npr>0</npr>
  <grossWeight>123.0</grossWeight>
  <goodsDescription>BOOKS</goodsDescription>
  <sdc>T</sdc>
  <status1Set></status1Set>
  <status2Set>true</status2Set>
  <ccsCreationTime>2011-05-25T21:17:00Z</ccsCreationTime>
  <customsStatus>
    <N1:code>CC</N1:code>
    <N1:statusText>Customs cleared</N1:statusText>
  </customsStatus>
  <customsSummaryText>TRED CLEARANCE</customsSummaryText>
  <customsSummaryTime>2011-05-25T21:30:00Z</customsSummaryTime>
  <agentReference>RS CFSP </agentReference>
  <isErtsPreArrival>false</isErtsPreArrival>
  <isAgentPreArrival>false</isAgentPreArrival>
  <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
  <finalised></finalised>
  <createdOn>2011-05-25T21:17:18.167Z</createdOn>
  <modifiedOn>2011-05-25T21:30:20.37Z</modifiedOn>
    </agentInventory>
```

The code used to deserialize this XML looks like this:

```
 var storeXmlInventoryReturnData = returnInventoryData.ReturnValue;

        if (storeXmlInventoryReturnData != null)
        {

            //DeSerialize XML from variable
            agentInventory myInventoryResponse = null;

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(agentInventory));
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(storeXmlInventoryReturnData));
            myInventoryResponse = (agentInventory)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memStream);

            Console.WriteLine(
             @"\n\n\n INVENTORY RETURN DATA FOR AWB: {0}-{1} \n\n 
                          Destination Port: {2} \n 
                          Arrival Port: {3} \n 
                          Carrier: {4} \n 
                          Flight No: {5} \n 
                          Flight Date: {6} \n 
                          Customers Status: {7} \n 
                          NPX: {8} \n
                          NPR {9} \n
                          SDC Code: {10}                              
                          \n\n Hit any key to exit...."
                ,

                myInventoryResponse.masterAirwayBillPrefix,
               myInventoryResponse.masterAirwayBillNumber,
                myInventoryResponse.destinationPort,
                myInventoryResponse.arrivalPort,
                myInventoryResponse.airCarrier,
                myInventoryResponse.flightNumber,
               myInventoryResponse.flightDate,
               myInventoryResponse.customsStatus,
                myInventoryResponse.npx,
                myInventoryResponse.npr,
                myInventoryResponse.sdc,
               myInventoryResponse.grossWeight,
                myInventoryResponse.goodsDescription
                    );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("No data returned");
        }
```

The line that throws the exception is

```
myInventoryResponse = (agentInventory)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memStream);
```

Comment: share the data class too.Also check your date time string is in correct format

Comment: In the code above, the whole `MemoryStream` is unnecessary since you seem to simply be parsing the XML from a string, which supports a `TextReader`. So `xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(storeXmlInventoryReturnData))` should achieve the same thing in a less complicated manner.

Comment: I think you might be onto something with date time format. Looking at some other code I have that correctly parses XML and the date time formats are different. The code that works for a different method returns a date time as 2014-10-16T11:07:00 and this code returns date time as 2011-05-25T21:17:18.167Z so I need to figure out how to manipulate the date time formats from within the XML

Comment: I'm afraid none of the above worked. I have looked at the exception in more details and the inner exception being thrown is "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object." Presumably  I need to convert the date time objects? i.e. myInventoryResponse.flightDate